# Setting FilePermissions in Java

Tags: java, file, file-permissions

In my program i want to create some temporary directories namely Temp1 and Temp2.

I am currently working on Mac and i choose the place to create these directories as

> /Users/your_account_username/Library/Application Support

This directory has the following File Permissions

```
> drwx------+  27 ib-mac-1  staff   918 May  7 19:01 Application Support
```

When i create Temp1 , i set read, write, execute permissions using the Java File API.

```
file.setExecutable(true);
file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(true);
```

Somehow this is not helping me apply rwx to the directories, the created directories/files under them are taking the only `drwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.setExecutable(boolean)`, `File.setReadable(boolean)` and `File.setWritable(boolean)` set only the *owner* permissions.

As `schmop` [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678438/545127), there are variants where you can indicate that you want the permissions set for everyone (`file.setReadable(true, false)`, etc).

However, if you want precise control of the POSIX file permissions (setting different other and group permissions, for example), the easiest solution is to use Java 7. Java 7 added the `Path` interface and `Paths` and `Files` classes as a replacement for `File`. It provides the method [`Files.setPosixFilePermissions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setPosixFilePermissions%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set%29), which can give you precisely the file permissions you want.

Comment: In java 6, there are variants to set for all users, for instance _setReadable(boolean readable, boolean ownerOnly)_

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
file.setExecutable(true, false);
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setWritable(true, false);
```

to set for all users.
Available in Java 6 (at least).

Comment: i see that if i apply this to the parent directory, only the parent directory gets 777. is there a way to do this recursive ? so that all children under parent get 777 ?

Comment: @shridatt Not automatically. You will have to traverse the children with the listFiles() method in the File class. However, if you are only executing your program on OSX, cosider using the exec() family of methods in the Runtime class. It will allow you to do most things available in a terminal, including chmod.